Why doesn't NAT Network Port Forwarding work in VirtualBox?
I'm setting up a VPN (LT2P/IPSec) Server in a Windows Server 2022 with RAS. The Server is in a NAT Network (172.16.1.0/24). I added the following NAT Rules:

I tried both with the Host IP empty, with my Host's machine and with the loopback address.
For some reason, when I try to connect on another VM on another Network, it doesn't work. It does work if they're on the same network, so it's not a VPN configuration problem. In the client i used my Host machine's IP Address.

NATRules in VirtualBox open the ports from the host to the guest. Have you also added NAT Rules on the router towards the Windows Server 2022 IP?

Yes, there Windows internal firewall must comply as well, otherwise the rules are redundant. Also, check for port conflicts.

What does 'another Network' mean – another actual network, or another VirtualBox NATNetwork? Can you draw a diagram of the entire thing? (Side question, if you're setting up L2TP/IPsec, do you really need the rules for PPTP and non-IPsec-L2TP ports?)
